# Trap and Stop the DDL Activity

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, ddl

I have a number of real life people who have access to the same Oracle account, and want to restrict some of these people from executing DDL on the basis of their OS users.

I want a trigger that fired on DDL commands and does not allow a user(selected people can perform the DDL activity) to Perform DDL activity on the Schema.

Regards 
ameer hamza

Comment: Do you want to prevent users performing DDL on their own schema? Or stop users with ANY level privileges performing DDL on some other schema?

Comment: yes i want to prevent the user to perform  DDL(create ,alter ,drop) on their own schema. only selected OS can perform DDL(create ,alter ,drop) .

Comment: I think you mean you have a number of real life people who have access to the same Oracle account, and want to restrict some of these people from executing DDL on the basis of their OS users. Is that it? If so please edit your question so it's clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If the @APC suggestion is correct, than Ithink you just need a second user, which will have view only access to the objects in the other schema. So, Schema1 is the owner (having the appropriate privileges, being THE owner) and Schema2, used by the users, which will have SELECT etc. privileges or will use PUBLIC SYNONYMS in order to access the objects in Schema1.

Comment: yes sir butt i want in schema some people can perform DDL activity